# iOS - changing constraint relation programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

given the following constraint in ios programmatically:

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint;
```

this constraint is linked in interfacebuilder to the following details:
[image]

How do I change the relation attribute programmatically.  I tried to look up for a method called setRelation but I don't see it.

Comment: What are you trying to do by changing the relation? There might be an easier way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/relation), `relation` is read-only.

What you will need to do, I suspect, is to set

```
self.myConstraint.active = NO;
```

Then make a new `NSLayoutConstraint` programmatically using:

[`+ constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:)

And in the process copying values you want to keep, and replacing the relation.

Then [add it to the view hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addConstraint:) where appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You can do like that :

```
  [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                 constraintWithItem:self.yellowView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:self.redView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                 multiplier:0.75
                                 constant:0.0]];
```